# Laravel storage get file causes problem in Google Chrome

Tags: laravel, storage

I tried to get file from storage of my Laravel Application like following: (Notice: In Firefox Files in pdf / jpeg format are directly been showed. Other files like docx or something is causing download).

```
    $contents = Storage::get("files/" . $file);
    return $contents;
```

In Google Chrome file is not showing and just shows me source of file like this (Following is example if I have a jpeg image) My whole desktop is full of following signs:

```
ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿÛ�„�
```

Do I have to set headers or something to show files in Google Chrome?

Comment: Which kind of file format is that?

Comment: this is first line of a jpeg image

Comment: Please share more details. Where do you set the headers for that response?

Comment: @SaschaK what you want ? download or get url ?

Comment: I don't set headers at the moment. I just get file and do return to show file in my browser, or if browser can`t show it should download.

Answer (score 2):

You can try instead :

```
$content = Storage::get("files/" . $file);
if (!File::exists($content)) {
    abort(404);
}
$file = Storage::get($content);
$type = Storage::mimeType($content);
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);

return $response;
```

Comment: This solution sends me out a "500 Internal Server Error", error: ArrayBuffer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```php
$file = File::get("files/" . $file);
$type = File::mimeType("files/" . $file); 
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);
```

Comment: $response = Response::make($file, 200); this brings out Error 500. Why?

Comment: You should use try catch block to find exact error.